# Slow response for the first request with AWS ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-application-load-balancer

I am using AWS and setup a VPC in us-west-2. There are public and private subnets in zone B and C. Mainly I use zone b only.

I have a NAT Gateway in public subnet in zone B and a t3a.large EC2 instance in private subnet in zone b too. I can run `curl https://google.com/` in my t3a instance in private subnet and the response time is very fast.

For ALB my setup is to listen 443 and forward it to my instance. I can curl locally on my instance and the respond time is very fast. However I am not sure why it is very very slow if I browse it with browser for the first time.

My application is full of XHR, and the slow response time only affect the very first request, for all sequential requests they are all fast.

When I have passed the first slow request and up to speed for me now. Another user with another computer starting to visit our site suffer from slow response time as he is newly visiting our site. The slow response time is definitely not caused by session or file transfer related issues.

Any ideas on what would be wrong?

Comment: You can refer [this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-fix-high-latency-on-alb/) from AWS to troubleshoot such issues.

Comment: Nobody can tell you what's wrong based on what you posted, other than "something takes a lot of time." [Enable access logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-access-logs.html) on your load balancer, and then edit this question or ask a new question based on what you see in those logs.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this problem? I am facing the same issue.. but from a mobile app. First request always takes long.. over 30 seconds, and the next ones go through with in a fraction of a second. This we noticed only on android mobile phones accessing internet with a mobile data plan. Same app when accessed with a wifi connection has no problem. We have an AWS ALB and apache logs on EC2 server show very low response time. At this point, I can tell ALB is the culprit - but how does it know that the request is from android app connecting with mobile data plan?

Comment: @ryadavalli Yes we sucessfully addressed the issue but I am sorry I cannot give you a clear answer. If I can recall my memory correctly, the problem is the ALB touches 2 zones: B and C(This is required for ALB even we actually 1 single instance in Zone B only) but we wrongly configured for Zone B to have internet access but not Zone C.(i.e. Only  Zone B has Internet Gateway set). Hope this reply is the big Xmas gift for you

Comment: @tom10271 Thanks for the prompt response. I did discover our Route 53 was configured a bit odd. It was not sending traffic directly to the ALB, rather routing to the main domain which in turn would direct the request to the code base (for example, xxx.yyy.com was going to yyy.com, and then yyy.com was directing traffic to ALB). I deleted the old CNAME records and created new A records to direct traffic from the subdomain to the ALB directly. This solved the problem. I am not sure what caused the ALB to slow down only specific requests and but not all requests. Problem resolved, so ok for now.

Comment: @tom10271 +1, your Xmas gift keeps on giving in 2022 :) that was our problem too. We accidentally configured _one_ of our ALB AZs to the wrong subnet. Correcting the subnet fixed the 30s+ delays/errors immediately.

Comment: @tom10271 That was my problem too, I would never find it... Much thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I had faced and successfully solved the same issue. I am running ECS cluster with 4 services, 1 task (container) each.

All of those containers run on EC2 instances in private network.

Those containers are accessible via Network Load Balancer.

The Load Balancer has 3 public IPs facing the internet, forwarded to 3 subnets in 3 Availability Zones.

1 EC2 instance can have only one subnet assigned, which means it resides in specific Availability Zone.

I was experiencing "long response times on first request". I started debugging and it seemed that Load Balancer was looking for an active target and then sticking the client to working target. I deduced that some of the networks must not respond properly.

I followed to "Network Mappings" in Load Balancer settings and tested each of the three public IPs (you have to assign custom Elastic IPs to each subnet to see the IPs).

I called each public ip and noticed that only one was working. It was the one that was assigned to subnet in the same Availability Zone as the EC2 instance.

In order for all IPs to work, you have to enable **Cross-zone load balancing** in Load Balancer attributes

I imagine there can be plenty of reasons for this issue, but it's always good to start by CURLing Load Balancers public-facing IPs.

Cheers!